# FFmpeg change audio sample rate

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to increase the sample rate by 10%. Sample rates of input files are unknown.

I found this. Example for 1 file:

```
ffmpeg -i xxx.mp3 -filter:a "asetrate=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=sample_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 xxx.mp3)*1.1" -y xxx1.mp3
```

But is is not working and creates 0kb file.

LOG:

> [asetrate @ 00000000024242e0] [Eval @ 00000000005fde80] Undefined
>   constant or missing '(' in
>   'ffprobe-verror-show_entriesstream=sample_rate-ofdefault=noprint_wrappers=1'
>   [asetrate @ 00000000024242e0] Unable to parse option value "$(ffprobe
>   -v error -show_entries stream=sample_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1" [Parsed_asetrate_0 @ 0000000000e6cb20]
>   Option 'nokey' not found [AVFilterGraph @ 0000000002419ca0] Error
>   initializing filter 'asetrate' with args '$(ffprobe -v error
>   -show_entries stream=sample_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 xxx.mp3)*1.1' Error reinitializing
>   filters! Failed to inject frame into filter network: Option not found
>   Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0 Conversion
>   failed!

Comment: Looks like your sub-command isn't working.

Comment: maybe. but this answer does not help at all.

Comment: Your question doesn't help at all.  You haven't tried to isolate the issue.  Are you using Bash?  Windows CMD?  Powershell?  What?

Comment: half of your speech is rubbish. Windows bat file.

Comment: @ValPan Brad's comments are valid, and resulted in you providing some important information that you omitted previously. No need to call them "rubbish". I'm not a Windows user, so I may be mistaken, but I do not believe that *nix shell style variable naming works in typical Windows bat files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape every ":" in your ffprobe command.